# CSS div nth child

Tags: css

I'm unable to add styles for nth child of child node. I'm able to find nth child but unable to find nth child of sub child node.

My sample HTML structure is:

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="test">
            <div class="sub1"/>
             <div class="sub2"/>
        </div>
         <div class="test">
             **<div class="sub2"/>**
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using below one, but not working.  I'm trying to select under second .test class

CSS:

```
.main:nth-of-type(2) .sub2{
}
.main:nth-child(2) .sub2{
}
```

Comment: ...none one of your tags have `subtest2` class...?

Comment: It's not clear to me which elements you're trying to select and are unable to. Please clarify which elements you're trying to target.

Comment: I'm trying to select under second .test class  **<div class="sub2"/>**

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might be the sort of thing you are looking for:

`.test:nth-child(2) .sub2 {`